# How to fix Error: Unknown option: .preset?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, preset

I'm try to npm start and got this err:

D:\CODE\WebDEV\Node_JS\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:135
throw unknownOptErr;
^

Error: Unknown option: .preset. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
at throwUnknownError (D:\CODE\WebDEV\Node_JS\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:133:27)
at D:\CODE\WebDEV\Node_JS\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:118:5
at Array.forEach ()
at validateNested (D:\CODE\WebDEV\Node_JS\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:94:21)
at validate (D:\CODE\WebDEV\Node_JS\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:85:10)
at D:\CODE\WebDEV\Node_JS\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:209:34
at cachedFunction (D:\CODE\WebDEV\Node_JS\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:60:27)
at cachedFunction.next () {
code: 'BABEL_UNKNOWN_OPTION'
}

Comment: Did you read the documentation the error provided?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.